# ADB cmd to get IMEI 2 is not working in android 11

Tags: android, adb, android-11, imei

I used to get both IMEIs of the dual sim device via adb using the following cmd and it was working fine.

**To get IMEI 1:**

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 3 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=
```

**To get IMEI 2:**

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=
```

But in S20 Ultra(Android 11), I cannot get IMEI 2 using the above cmd.

Even I tried using the "iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1" and "iphonesubinfo 3 i32 2", but it returns empty.

**Transition codes of iphonesubinfo used:**

- 1 - getDeviceId
- 2 - getDeviceIdForSubscriber
- 3 - getImeiForSubscriber
- 4 - getDeviceSvn
- 5 - getSubscriberId
- 6 - getSubscriberIdForSubscriber

**Question:**

1. Is these transition codes changed for android 10? If so pls share the updated to get the IMEI2.
2. Or is it happening due to the Hybrid sim slot of s20 Ultra? If so how to get IMEI 2 of hybrid sim slot?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Try with the following command to get IMEI 1 and IMEI 2 for hybrid sim devices on Android 11

**To get IMEI 1:**

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 4 i32 2 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=
```

**To get IMEI 2:**

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 4 i32 1 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=
```